# WPF await switches from the UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a function called from the UI thread, I'm double checking if that's so by

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
```

everything is called from a `void` method, which can't be `async void` because it has an `out` parameter (method from 3rd party API).

So in this `void` method I make a call to an `async` method, the main method doesn't have to wait, so I just run it and forget (planning to handle exceptions in the `ContinueWith` method, but I'm not there yet).

Problem is, that when in the method chain an `await` is performed on the `ExecuteTaskAsync` method of the RestSharp client, after that line, the thread is witched to MTA, the `SynchronizationContext.Current` is different too.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the `await` keyword return to the orginal SynchronizationContext? Why is the `SynchronizationContext.Current` changing during that call?

Sorry for no code snippets, it's a part of a bigger app and it's hard to snippet it out, but I'm doing it right now, so code snippets will be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, resolved it, the mentioned `void` method from the 3rd party API, was running with a thread that has a dispatcher, because

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
```

Returned a dispatcher, I don't know why, but that didn't matter, I had to run my async method in an `Invoke` like

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => myAsyncMethod());
```

and then the `await` in my method didn't switched the `SynchronizationContext`.
It looks like my assumption that when there is a dispatcher it's the proper context was wrong, don't know why :)